# "Group by" with XSLT in Search Core Results web part

Tags: 2010, web-part, xslt, search-results

I have a bit of difficulty making it possible to group by the results in search core results webpart.

I have a default xslt of that webpart and from there i would like to group the results by the sitename (managed property) could anyone give me a hint or provide me some useful xslt?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are going to struggle to do this effectively.

Search results in the core results web part are generally paged so any grouping that you do will only apply to that page of results.

When you go to the next page then the grouping will be for that page of results.

Unless you are able to restrict the number of results to a reasonable number that you can show on a single page then I don't think it will be usable.  Too many results on the same page leads to a lot of data being returned by search and potential performance issues.

Hope this helps.